# Find extreme values of implicit function $x^2+2y^2+4z^2-2x+12y+8z+19=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find extreme values of implicit function $x^2+2y^2+4z^2-2x+12y+8z+19=0$

I have found partial derivative with respect to x and y and they are:

$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{2-2x}{8z-8} => x=1$
$\frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{-4y-12}{8z+8} => y=-3$
$\frac{d}{dz}=8z+8 => z=-1$

Now my critical point would be $A(1,-3,-1)$ is this correct?

Comment: Your question makes no sense because if you are given that $x^2 + 2y^2 + 4z^2 - 2x + 12y + 8z + 19 = 0$, then any choice of $(x,y,z)$ satisfying this equation will give you zero.  In other words, you are asking for an extremum for an implicit function that is **constant** by construction.

Comment: You have written an equation whereas it should be just a quadratic expression of $x,y,z$

Answer (score 1):

Note: Do not say that the expression is zero. Instead, say find max/mim value of T

Let $T=x^2+2y^2+4z^2-2x+12y+8z+19=(x-1)^2+2(y+3)^2+4(z+1)^2-4$
$$\implies T+4\ge 0\implies T_{min}=-4$$
The min occurs when $x=1, y=-3,z=-1$.

Comment: The question states that $T = 0$ by definition, therefore it makes no sense to find an extremum.

Comment: Yes I have added a note for your point.

Comment: Then it is no longer an implicit function, but an explicit one, namely $T : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$.  The fact that the question states in multiple ways that $T$ is part of an implicit relation seems to suggest a more serious defect in the question than can be justifiably remedied by simply modifying the problem.  For instance, why not turn it into a problem that locates the points satisfying $T = 0$ with extremal distance from the origin?  That is just as legitimate an interpretation and without correction, it is not possible to know the original intent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if "critical point" is applicable here because you have an equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ rather than a function $f(x,y,z)$. Indeed, $(1,-3,-1)$ is an extreme for $f(x,y,z)$ but it is not at the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$.

The implicite function could be written as :
$$
(x-1)^2+2(y+3)^2+4(z+1)^2 = 4
$$
Assume that you want to find extreme value of $z$ w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, it is clear that the $(z+1)^2 \in [0,1] $ so $z+1 \in [-1,1]$, and then $z \in [-2,0]$. So we have

- $z_{min} = -2$, with $x=1$ and $y=-3$
- $z_{max} = 0$, with $x=1$ and $y=-3$

Same logic could be used to find $x_{min/max}$ w.r.t. $y$ and $z$, and $y_{min/max}$ w.r.t. $x$ and $z$.

Hope this could help you.